# XPath: Select All Text of Descendants where first Div attribute matches condition

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Please consider the following code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://advisorless.substack.com/?no_cover=true')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Within the HTML, the relevant sections are something like:

```
<div class="body markup">
  <p>123</p>
  <a href=''>456</a>
</div>

<div class="body markup">
  <p>ABC</p>
  <p>DEF</p>
</div>
```

**Attempt 1**

`tree.xpath('//div[@class="body markup"]/descendant::*/text()')`

Produces the following result:  `['123', '456', 'ABC', 'DEF']`

**Attempt 2**

`tree.xpath('//div[@class="body markup"]/descendant::*/text()')[0]`

Produces the following result:  `['123']`

**What I Want to Get**  `['123', '456']`

I'm not sure if this can be done with a sibling selector instead of descendants

**For Specific URL:**

The following code from Inspect Element is the result I'm looking for; although my code needs something more dynamic.  Where div[3] is the div with class="body markup":

`//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article/div[3]/descendant::*/text()')`

For more specificity, this also works:

`//div[@class="post-list"]/div[1]/div/article[@class="post"]/div[@class="body markup"]/descendant::*/text()`

It's that one static div that I don't know how to modify. I'm sure there's a simple piece I'm not putting together.

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: should have done that in the first place. apologies.  https://advisorless.substack.com/?no_cover=true.  the `body markup` classes delimit separate blog posts.

Comment: Your url has 5 `body markup`s followed by `p`s. Are you always looking for the first `body markup` with a following `a`, or is there some other method for selection? Also, can you paste (at least part of) the desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm looking to extract all the text (including descendants) within the `body markup` class.  The last two xpath commands in my post get me the desired output in this instance, but with a static `div[1]` selection in the middle.  Ideally, I would like to be able to traverse the 5 `body markup` sections more dynamically... maybe this is not possible?  Or maybe I could modify my code elsewhere to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are after, but let's start with this and let me know how to modify the outcome, if necessary:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://advisorless.substack.com/?no_cover=true"
resp = requests.get(url)

root = html.fromstring(resp.text)
targets = root.xpath("//div[@class='body markup'][./p][./a]")
for target in targets:
    print(target.text_content())
    for link in target.xpath('a'):
        print(link.attrib['href'])
    print('=====')
```

The output is too long to reproduce here, but see if it fits your desired output.